# Why does this 3V linear voltage regulator output 1.6V?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, surface-mount

[image]

This regulator in my faulty airplane remote that can't turn on is outputting unstable voltage that swings around 1.6V - 1.5V at pin 5. My multimeter shows that the input voltage is stable at 3.3V on pin 1. According to its datasheet, it should output 3V.

The regulator will quickly get extremely hot when I try to turn on my remote. When I try to turn on my remote, the screen turns on and off quickly like it doesn't have enough power.

Is this regulator the reason my remote won't turn on?

Answer (score 5):

Something else downstream of the regulator is broken and shorted, or just consuming too much current.

The regulator can't provide enough current so the output voltage does not reach the intended value and it dissipates too much power.

See what else is heating up in the circuit to fix it. I don't think the regulator is the issue here.

Comment: Thanks, thats a good idea. Do you have any tips on what to look for? This board is dense with electronic components. I dont know where to start. Maybe capacitors?

Comment: No, I don't have a clue. All I see from here is the photo you posted with maybe 5 components.

Comment: @Pushies Thermal camera if possible, or some other way to look for heat. If you put your finger on a chip and it's hot, that's probably the culprit. I have heard a trick is to put little dabs of rubbing alcohol on the board and see which evaporates. (Don't quote me on that, though, if it ends up shorting stuff out). Where the heat is (other than this regulator) is likely to be the problem.